# docker toolbox mount file on windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am a beginner with docker and I am using a windows machine. But I have a problem mounting files using volumes. The documentation says the following thing about mount files on OSX and windows :

**[Official docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)**

Note: If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon only has limited access to your OS X/Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your `/Users` (OS X) or `C:\Users` (Windows) directory - and so you can mount files or directories using `docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`  (OS X) or `docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path ...` (Windows). All other paths come from your virtual machine’s filesystem.

I have a small nginx **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM centos:6.6

MAINTAINER afym

ENV WEBPORT 80

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all

RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all

RUN yum -y install nginx; yum clean all

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE $WEBPORT

CMD [ "/usr/sbin/nginx" ]
```

**Creating a simple container**

```
docker run -d --name simple -p 8082:80 ng1
```

8875448c01a4787f1ffe4c4c5c492efb039e452eff957391ac52a08915e18d66

[image]

**Creating a container with a volume**

My windows host directory

[image]

**Creating the docker container with -v option**

```
docker run -d --name simple2 -v /c/Users/src:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8082:80 ng1
```

```
invalid value "C:\\Users\\src;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\nginx\\html" 
for flag -v: bad mount mode specified 
: \Program Files\Git\usr\share\nginx\html
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

**Inspecting the ng1 image**

```
docker inspect ng1
```

[image]

What is wrong when I am creating a docker container with a volume?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running container from outside boot2docker VM?

Comment: Since you are using `Windows` and as you said you are a beginner in docker , i would like to suggest you to please look at [Kinematic](https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/) once.
Its a lucid way to understand **mounting of volumes**, **manage containers** etc.. i hope it helps. :) Cheers

Comment: Just realize that even you got correct mounting config, **docker inspect ng1** will remain to show **"Volumes" { "/usr/share/nginx/html": {}}**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to run it with additional `/` for volume like:

```
docker run -d --name simple2 -v /c/Users/src://usr/share/nginx/html -p 8082:80 ng1
```

Or even for host OS, as

```
docker run -d --name simple2 -v //c/Users/src://usr/share/nginx/html -p 8082:80 ng1
```

Due to this [issue](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/80):

> This is something that the MSYS environment does to map POSIX paths to Windows paths before passing them to executables.

Comment: As a side note for Windows, if you had mounted the volume without specifying the source, the Source path that `docker inspect` reports is in the VM running docker, which you can access with `docker-machine ssh` or by accessing the VM through VirtualBox or whichever provider is in use.

Answer (score 4):

As the OP said:

> [Official docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) :
>
> Note: If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker
> daemon only has limited access to your OS X/Windows filesystem. Docker
> Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows)
> directory - and so you can mount files or directories using
> docker run -v /Users/:/ ... (OS X)
> or
> docker run -v /c/Users/:/

But if you want access to other directories, you need to add a new shared folder to the virtual box settings (Settings > Shared Folders > Add share).

Add there a new share (only possible when you stop the vm before, `docker-machine stop`:

```
path C:\Projects
name c/Projects
autoMount yes
```

Or edit directly the vbox configuration file
`C:\Users\<username>\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.vbox`

Add there into `<SharedFolders>` the line

```
<SharedFolder name="c/Projects" hostPath="\\?\c:\Projects" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
```

Restart the machine:

```
docker-machine stop
docker-machine start
```

Now, it's possible to mount also directories with the base `C:\Projects`

```
docker run -v //c/Projects/myApp://myApp <myImage>
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using docker ~> 1.12 and faces this issue.  I spent 30min trying to figure it out until i realized you have to specifically share a drive first via docker settings, see:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/shared-drives

Comment: Note that this is for Docker for Windows, not for Docker Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to access a local drive, the MINGW32 Docker Toolbox terminal puts the root of each drive in `/<drive-letter>`, so drive `C:\` will be at `/c/`