# Using absolute path with docker run command not working

Tags: docker

What's the difference between these two docker run commands and why one is working and the other does not.

**Working Command**

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=$HOME/neo4j_test/data:/data neo4j`

**Not Working**

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=C:/Users/USERNAME/neo4j_test/data:/data neoj`

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=C:\Users\USERNAME\neo4j_test\data:/data neo4j`

Error for these commands

> C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "C:UsersUSERNAMEneo4j_testdata:/data": invalid mode: /data.
> See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

In the non-working commands, I just replaced `$HOME` with the absolute path for my user profile folder `C:/Users/USERNAME`

**UPDATE**

I did inspect the value for `$HOME` by executing `echo $HOME` on Windows Powershell. And it is in fact `C:\Users\USERNAME`. I also did look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312662/docker-toolbox-mount-file-on-windows) that @Titouan Freville has commented. So I used the command

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=/c/Users/USERNAME/neo4j_test/data:/data neo4j`

isntead of

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=C:/Users/USERNAME/neo4j_test/data:/data neoj`

and it is working now. Right now I'm just wondering where the transformation of `$HOME` from `C:\Users\USERNAME` to `/c/Users/USERNAME` happens

Comment: Could you provide us with the error message ? You should have one. If it is a not found file, make sure that $HOME == C:/Users/USERNAME also you should look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312662/docker-toolbox-mount-file-on-windows. It could be an answer.

Comment: @TitouanFreville please see update :)

Comment: try `--volume=C:\/Users\/USERNAME/\neo4j_test/\data:/data`

Comment: guess it is the way Docker Machine is interpreting the path. He should transform it to a linux like version compatible with him ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To close the subject. Here is the solution ;) [docker toolbox mount file on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312662/docker-toolbox-mount-file-on-windows)

Also, the interpolation of $HOME by docker on windows have to be compatible with it, so it should transform it by himself when you call it in docker command.

Comment: Just an additional note to this answer. The drive letter should be in lower case. For instance this will work `/c/Users/USERNAME` and this will not `/C/Users/USERNAME`

Comment: If using git-bash on windows add an extra slash, ie: 

`-v /c/path:/path`

to 

`-v //c/path:/path`

Comment: Or in case of the docker tutorial: `docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w //c/path/to-docker-tutorial/getting-started/app -v "$(pwd):/app" node:12-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"` - so, also the extra slash for the working directory

Answer (score 29):

For anyone still having this problem with Docker-for-Windows, here are the 2 solutions that work:

### Prefix your command

with `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`

*In full*: `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 docker run -v /c/path:/path`

### Use double-slashes

`//` at the beginning

*In full*: `docker run -v //c/path:/path`

---

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029#issuecomment-250412919