# Run Docker container with jenkins pipeline always results on it needs to be an absolute path

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i've my windows 10 machine with docker and jenkins for windows and i'm trying to create a jenkins job usign pipelines where i want ro run a build inside a docker container, and for some reason when i start the build it always result in the same following error:

**java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'myimage:tag'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2/' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.**

before the error occours, i see that is trying to run with the following command automatically

```
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -d -t -w D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2/ -v D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2/:D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2/ -v D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2@tmp/:D:/jenkins/workspace/jobname@2@tmp/ -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ********...
```

My jenkinsfile is as simple as this

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'myimage:tag'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls -lha'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do to solve this issue? any ideas?

Comment: Is your "D:/jenkins/workspace" part of the list of shared folders as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#volumes)

Comment: I guess it is about slave image. Is it a slave image that you are using?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with docker CLI for windows - https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the knowledge base, I am getting a similar result with this [hello jenkins](https://github.com/hello-jenkins-larkintuckerllc/hello-jenkins).

I get:

```
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -d -t -w D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5/ -v D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5/:D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5/ -v D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5@tmp/:D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5@tmp/
```

followed by:

```
"java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'golang:1.14'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'D:/jenkins/home/workspace/p5/' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
```

Relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213524/using-absolute-path-with-docker-run-command-not-working).

Edit 1: this [windows and docker](https://ngeor.com/2019/12/25/windows-docker-and-paths.html) looks like it might be a fix. But how to tell what shell docker is running?

Edit 2: This a common problem. This [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20working%20directory%22%20%22is%20invalid%2C%20it%20needs%20to%20be%20an%20absolute%20path.%22%20windows%2010&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01KYNWWQReuAMxk0ggGIbfveBgsMQ%3A1619688098939&ei=onqKYKTiOLrL0PEPqMW6uA0&oq=%22the%20working%20directory%22%20%22is%20invalid%2C%20it%20needs%20to%20be%20an%20absolute%20path.%22%20windows%2010&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BggAEAgQHjoHCCMQrgIQJ1Cwb1icrgFgmLIBaAFwAngAgAGmAYgB4gSSAQM1LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiku6KukKPwAhW6JTQIHaiiDtcQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) gets about 1500 hits.

Edit 3: [This](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204) may be where the problem is.